# Which one is faster to open/edit, .doc or .docx file using MS Word2016 on macOS sierra

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, memory, microsoft-office, macos-sierra

My Macbook Pro has been having performance issue. I usually do SMC reset when it's happened but It's been kept frequently now a days. I may have to reinstall MS office or macOS sierra. Unfortunately, I don't have enough time to investigate for the moment which process is disturbing and leaking memory. I noticed MS that Excel2016 has memory leak issue. Now MS is aware of the issue. But They can not fix it immediately like Google and this doc file issue. However, I have to develop(create) and edit documents using MS Word 2016 for Mac which is one of the application of MS Office 365 Solo. Could you tell me which one is faster to edit and open, doc or docx file using MS Word 2016 on macOS Sierra, and benefit if there are?

Sorry this time, I use Mac in Japanese Language mode. So you can see Japanese character in the screenshot.(I will change language mode for the next time) If you may take a look.
[Activity Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvSJB.png)

Thank you.

My MacBookPro
Mid-2012/DualCore/i5/2.5Ghz/HTT/8GB/500GB macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: I found the answer that docx is smaller than doc file so it's faster than doc file to open docx. In our office, They are kind of legacy guy we have been using doc file. I have to propagate this matter to user.

Comment: Please close this or removed this